# Pandas: Running a calculation on rows of a data table based on multiple columns and storing the output in a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, distance, haversine

I am trying to calculate the distance from 2 locations and I've been provided with the longitude and latitude for the both destination. In my CSV, I have 4 columns (lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2), How do I apply the code below so that I create a 5th column called 'Distance' with the distance calculated using the code below?

```
import math
from math import sin, cos, sqrt, atan2, radians

# approximate radius of earth in km
R = 6373.0

#Test
lat1 = radians(25.2296756)
lon1 = radians(36.0122287)
lat2 = radians(51.406374)
lon2 = radians(20.9251681)

dlon = lon2 - lon1
dlat = lat2 - lat1

a = sin(dlat / 2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon / 2)**2
c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))

distance = R * c

print("Result:", distance)
print("Should be:", 3181.11, "km")
```

[image: Columns example in CSV]

**Dataframe:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Normalised': {(0, 'London,', 'United', 'Kingdom'): '-',
  (1, 'Johannesburg,', 'South', 'Africa'): '-',
  (2, 'London,', 'United', 'Kingdom'): '-',
  (3, 'Johannesburg,', 'South', 'Africa'): '-',
  (4, 'London,', 'United', 'Kingdom'): '-'},
 'City': {(0, 'London,', 'United', 'Kingdom'): 'New',
  (1, 'Johannesburg,', 'South', 'Africa'): 'London,',
  (2, 'London,', 'United', 'Kingdom'): 'New',
  (3, 'Johannesburg,', 'South', 'Africa'): 'London,',
  (4, 'London,', 'United', 'Kingdom'): 'Singapore,'},
 'Pair': {(0, 'London,', 'United', 'Kingdom'): 'York,',
  (1, 'Johannesburg,', 'South', 'Africa'): 'United',
  (2, 'London,', 'United', 'Kingdom'): 'York,',
  (3, 'Johannesburg,', 'South', 'Africa'): 'United',
  (4, 'London,', 'United', 'Kingdom'): 'Singapore'},
 'Departure': {(0, 'London,', 'United', 'Kingdom'): 'United',
  (1, 'Johannesburg,', 'South', 'Africa'): 'Ki...',
  (2, 'London,', 'United', 'Kingdom'): 'United',
  (3, 'Johannesburg,', 'South', 'Africa'): 'Ki...',
  (4, 'London,', 'United', 'Kingdom'): 'SIN'},
 'Code': {(0, 'London,', 'United', 'Kingdom'): 'Stat.',
  (1, 'Johannesburg,', 'South', 'Africa'): 'JNB',
  (2, 'London,', 'United', 'Kingdom'): 'Stat',
  (3, 'Johannesburg,', 'South', 'Africa'): 'JNB',
  (4, 'London,', 'United', 'Kingdom'): 'LHR'},
 'Arrival': {(0, 'London,', 'United', 'Kingdom'): 'LHR',
  (1, 'Johannesburg,', 'South', 'Africa'): 'LHR',
  (2, 'London,', 'United', 'Kingdom'): 'LHR',
  (3, 'Johannesburg,', 'South', 'Africa'): 'LHR',
  (4, 'London,', 'United', 'Kingdom'): '1.3'},
 'Code.1': {(0, 'London,', 'United', 'Kingdom'): 'JFK',
  (1, 'Johannesburg,', 'South', 'Africa'): '-26.1',
  (2, 'London,', 'United', 'Kingdom'): 'JFK',
  (3, 'Johannesburg,', 'South', 'Africa'): '-26.1',
  (4, 'London,', 'United', 'Kingdom'): '103.98'},
 'Departure_lat': {(0, 'London,', 'United', 'Kingdom'): 51.5,
  (1, 'Johannesburg,', 'South', 'Africa'): 28.23,
  (2, 'London,', 'United', 'Kingdom'): 51.5,
  (3, 'Johannesburg,', 'South', 'Africa'): 28.23,
  (4, 'London,', 'United', 'Kingdom'): 51.47},
 'Departure_lon': {(0, 'London,', 'United', 'Kingdom'): -0.45,
  (1, 'Johannesburg,', 'South', 'Africa'): 51.47,
  (2, 'London,', 'United', 'Kingdom'): -0.45,
  (3, 'Johannesburg,', 'South', 'Africa'): 51.47,
  (4, 'London,', 'United', 'Kingdom'): -0.45},
 'Arrival_lat': {(0, 'London,', 'United', 'Kingdom'): 40.64,
  (1, 'Johannesburg,', 'South', 'Africa'): -0.45,
  (2, 'London,', 'United', 'Kingdom'): 40.64,
  (3, 'Johannesburg,', 'South', 'Africa'): -0.45,
  (4, 'London,', 'United', 'Kingdom'): np.nan},
 'Arrival_lon': {(0, 'London,', 'United', 'Kingdom'): -73.79,
  (1, 'Johannesburg,', 'South', 'Africa'): np.nan,
  (2, 'London,', 'United', 'Kingdom'): -73.79,
  (3, 'Johannesburg,', 'South', 'Africa'): np.nan,
  (4, 'London,', 'United', 'Kingdom'): np.nan}})
```

Comment: So this question is really more about adding a new column to a dataframe/csv rather than about the calculation of the distance right?

Comment: Correct, I've changed the title as its incorrect

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You need to clearer about what you want done.

Comment: I've tried to make my question clearer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a custom function for the distance calculation.  Then, use [`.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to call and apply the function on each row to get the distance for each row.

**1. Define a custom function for the distance calculation, as follows:**

```
import math
from math import sin, cos, sqrt, atan2, radians

def get_distance(in_lat1, in_lon1, in_lat2, in_lon2):
    # approximate radius of earth in km
    R = 6373.0

    lat1 = radians(in_lat1)
    lon1 = radians(in_lon1)
    lat2 = radians(in_lat2)
    lon2 = radians(in_lon2)

    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    dlat = lat2 - lat1

    a = sin(dlat / 2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon / 2)**2
    c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))

    distance = R * c

    return distance
```

**2. Use [`.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to call and apply the function on each row to get the distance for each row, as follows:**

```
df['Distance'] = df.apply(lambda x: get_distance(x['Departure_lat'], x['Departure_lon'], x['Arrival_lat'], x['Arrival_lon']), axis=1)
```

### Demo

**Input Dataframe**

```
        City  Departure_lat  Departure_lon  Arrival_lat  Arrival_lon
0  CityName1      25.229676      36.012229    51.406374    20.925168
```

**Output**

```
        City  Departure_lat  Departure_lon  Arrival_lat  Arrival_lon    Distance
0  CityName1      25.229676      36.012229    51.406374    20.925168  3181.11039
```

Comment: Hi dude ,since you're so helpful, could help my other issue pleaseee https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68691080/how-to-clean-data-so-that-the-correct-arrival-code-is-there-for-the-city-pair

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide the data, so I made up my own based on your question; just use the `numpy` version of those functions on your columns.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

row = pd.Series({
    "lat1": 25.2296756,
    "lon1": 36.0122287,
    "lat2": 51.406374,
    "lon2": 20.9251681
})
df = pd.concat([row]*5, axis=1).T.apply(np.radians)

df["dlon"] = df.lon2 - df.lon1
df["dlat"] = df.lat2 - df.lat1

R = 6373
a = np.sin(df.dlat / 2)**2 + np.cos(df.lat1) * np.cos(df.lat2) * np.sin(df.dlon / 2)**2
c = 2 * np.arctan2(np.sqrt(a), np.sqrt(1 - a))
df["distance"] = R*c
```

The resulting dataframe looks like this:

```
       lat1      lon1     lat2      lon2      dlon     dlat    distance
0  0.440341  0.628532  0.89721  0.365213 -0.263319  0.45687  3181.11039
1  0.440341  0.628532  0.89721  0.365213 -0.263319  0.45687  3181.11039
2  0.440341  0.628532  0.89721  0.365213 -0.263319  0.45687  3181.11039
3  0.440341  0.628532  0.89721  0.365213 -0.263319  0.45687  3181.11039
4  0.440341  0.628532  0.89721  0.365213 -0.263319  0.45687  3181.11039
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make your `dlon`, `dlat`, `a`, and `c` all as some temp columns and then calculate from there (or have it all in one difficult to read line).

Something like:

```py
df['dlon'] = df['Arrival_lon'] - df['Departure_lon']
df['dlat'] = df['Arrival_lat'] - df['Departure_lat']

df['a'] = sin(df['dlat'] / 2)**2 + cos(df['Departure_lat']) * cos(df['Arrival_lat']) * sin(df['dlon'] / 2)**2
df['c'] = 2 * atan2(sqrt(df['a']), sqrt(1 - df['a']))

df['distance'] = R * df['c']
```

Then you can `.drop()` all those extra columns if you want, but that should create df['distance'] as a new column calculated for each row.

I wouldn't be surprised if I have a typo in that code, but hopefully you get the idea. Each `df[xxx] =`  line makes that new column.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your calculation code in a function:

```
def calculate_distance(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2):
  # approximate radius of earth in km
  R = 6373.0

  lat1 = radians(lat1)
  lon1 = radians(lon1)
  lat2 = radians(lat2)
  lon2 = radians(lon2)

  dlon = lon2 - lon1
  dlat = lat2 - lat1

  a = sin(dlat / 2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon / 2)**2
  c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))

  distance = R * c

  return distance
```

And then apply it to each row with List Comprehension:

```
df['distance'] = [calculate_distance(row.lat1, row.lon1, row.lat2, row.lon2) for row in df.itertuples() ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your data csv file is formatted something similar to the following could be used.

In essence you need to turn your calculation into a callable function and then call it on every row in your data file which can be imported into python using the csv library.

```py
import math
import csv # Added import for importing csv into python.
from math import sin, cos, sqrt, atan2, radians

# Import the data from the csv file.
with open('data.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    data = list(csv.reader(csvfile))
    
# Approximate radius of earth in km.
R = 6373.0

# Create a distance calculation function.
def calculate_distance(lat1_d, lon1_d, lat2_d, lon2_d):
    
    # Convert from degrees to radians.
    lat1 = radians(lat1_d)
    lon1 = radians(lon1_d)
    lat2 = radians(lat2_d)
    lon2 = radians(lon2_d)

    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    dlat = lat2 - lat1

    a = sin(dlat / 2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon / 2)**2
    c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))
    
    distance = R * c
    return distance
    
# Use list comprehension to run function on every data row.
distances = [calculate_distance(row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3]) for row in data]

# Append distance column to original array to create output.
output = [row + [distance[index]] for index,row in enumerate(data)]
```

Please be aware that the `row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3]` refers to the order of the columns in the data array/csv file. These may need to be reordered as need be, to coincide with the function's declared input order, i.e: `lat1_d, lon1_d, lat2_d, lon2_d`.

```py
# Import the data from the csv file.
with open('data.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    data = list(csv.reader(csvfile))
```

These import parameters will also need to be tweaked to account for the format and name of the csv file.

Comment: Also works like a charm.. god bless ya ser!

Comment: @RedRum glad to hear, took me a while to put together! If you feel this is the most complete answer please could you consider accepting it as correct by clicking the ✓, thanks.