# How to clean data so that the correct arrival code is there for the city pair?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

How to clean data so that the correct arrival code is there for the city pair?

From the picture, the CSV is like column 1: City Pair (Departure - Arrival), column 2 is meant to be the Departure Code, and column 3 is meant to be the Arrival Code.

As you can see for row 319 in the first column, it is 'London - Paris', column 2 is CDG, and column 3 is LHR when it should be the opposite.

Also in row 324, Dusseldorf - Paris is CDG in column 2 and DUS in column 3, when it should be the opposite.

The majority of the CSV is correct, but there are a lot of errors like this.

Could someone help on how to sort this for all the rows? Maybe indexing through all of the rows in column 1 and making sure the text before and after the '-' matches the codes in columns 2 and 3?

[image: Columns example in CSV]

```
    old_index   airports                                arr dep
0   319         London, United Kingdom - Paris, France  CDG LHR
1   320         London, United Kingdom - Paris, France  CDG LHR
2   321         London, United Kingdom - Paris, France  CDG LHR
3   322         London, United Kingdom - Paris, France  CDG LHR
4   323         London, United Kingdom - Paris, France  CDG LHR
5   324         Dusseldorf, Germany - Paris, France     CDG DUS
6   325         Amsterdam, Netherlands - Paris, France  CDG AMS
7   326         Amsterdam, Netherlands - Paris, France  CDG AMS
8   327         Amsterdam, Netherlands - Paris, France  CDG AMS
9   328         Amsterdam, Netherlands - Paris, France  CDG AMS
10  329         Amsterdam, Netherlands - Paris, France  CDG AMS
```

Comment: Please, [do not post images of data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/285557#285557). You may check [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) to apply appropriate formatting to the tabular data.

Comment: Sorry apparently it needed a certain number of reps to correctly format the picture? I think someone did it for me in a previous thread tho

Comment: Do you have a mapping that specifies the appropriate city for each code?  And tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Hi Gordon, I do not have mapping, but now I have search on google for airport city codes and found https://www.ccra.com/airport-codes/ . I'm thinking this could be used as a reference and then adding the correct codes in the 'arr' and 'dep' column, based off the 'airport' column ? I may have to do some web scraping first to get all these codes of the website? This project is getting more complicated by the minute lol Also I've been using python and panda database.. thanks

Comment: You'll probably split `London, United Kingdom - Paris, France` with the `-`.  However, consider how you then map `London, United Kingdom` (in your frame) to `London Heathrow Airport` in `EGLL,large_airport,London Heathrow Airport,83,EU,GB,GB-ENG,London,EGLL,LHR,,"51.4706, -0.461941"` in the CSV link.

Comment: ...example: https://ibb.co/SQhGDt7

Comment: ahaha I literally just figured out how to split it then add it concatenate it.. it took me over an hour to figure out then you post this lmao thank you tho!  I used import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('FlightDistanceTest.csv')
split_city = df['Normalised City Pair'].str.split(' - ', expand=True)
df_out = pd.concat([df, split_city], axis=1)
df_out.columns = list(range(len(df_out.columns)))
df_out

Comment: So now that the cities have been split from Arrival and Destination, I would need a dataframe with the correct cities and codes? It looks like https://www.ccra.com/airport-codes/ has the correct codes but but the cities are in a different format... sigh Any idea mate?

Comment: I've found this site with the city, country and IATA codes in a good format. https://www.world-airport-codes.com/alphabetical/airport-code/b.html?page=1  So maybe reference to the city and country in the list for correct codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an example, and using the **cleaner** looking data from your other question...

**Given:**

[image]

..from [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68686217/inserting-my-multiple-columns-to-equations-and-creating-a-new-column).

**Try:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
from math import sin, cos, sqrt, atan2, radians

def get_distance(in_lat1, in_lon1, in_lat2, in_lon2):
    # approximate radius of earth in km
    R = 6373.0

    lat1 = radians(in_lat1)
    lon1 = radians(in_lon1)
    lat2 = radians(in_lat2)
    lon2 = radians(in_lon2)

    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    dlat = lat2 - lat1

    a = sin(dlat / 2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon / 2)**2
    c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))

    distance = R * c

    return distance

df = pd.DataFrame({'Normalised City Pair': {0: 'London, United Kingdom - New York, United States',
  1: 'Johannesburg, South Africa - London, United Kingdom',
  2: 'London, United Kingdom - New York, United States',
  3: 'Johannesburg, South Africa - London, United Kingdom',
  4: 'London, United Kingdom - Singapore, Singapore'},
 'Departure Code': {0: 'LHR', 1: 'JNB', 2: 'LHR', 3: 'JNB', 4: 'SIN'},
 'Arrival Code': {0: 'JFK', 1: 'LHR', 2: 'JFK', 3: 'LHR', 4: 'LHR'},
 'Departure_lat': {0: 51.5, 1: -26.1, 2: 51.5, 3: -26.1, 4: 1.3},
 'Departure_lon': {0: -0.45, 1: 28.23, 2: -0.45, 3: 28.23, 4: 103.98},
 'Arrival_lat': {0: 40.64, 1: 51.47, 2: 40.64, 3: 51.47, 4: 51.47},
 'Arrival_lon': {0: -73.79, 1: -0.45, 2: -73.79, 3: -0.45, 4: -0.45}})

df_airports = pd.read_csv('https://ourairports.com/data/airports.csv')
df_airports = df_airports[['name', 'iata_code']].copy()
df_airports = df_airports[df_airports['iata_code'].notna()].reset_index(drop=True)
# df_airports.query('iata_code == "CDG" | iata_code == "LHR"')

df['Distance'] = df.apply(lambda x: get_distance(x['Departure_lat'], x['Departure_lon'], x['Arrival_lat'], x['Arrival_lon']), axis=1)

#df[['ap_dep', 'ap_arr']] = df['Normalised City Pair'].str.split(' - ', expand=True)

df_airports = df_airports.sort_values('name')

df_airports = df_airports.drop_duplicates(subset ='iata_code', keep='first')

df['dep_ap_name'] = df['Departure Code'].map(df_airports.set_index('iata_code')['name'])
df['arr_ap_name'] = df['Arrival Code'].map(df_airports.set_index('iata_code')['name'])
```

**Output:**

[image]

If the frame now has too many columns and you want something cleaner and to reorder the columns try `final_df = df[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]` where abc are the columns and ordering you would like.

Comment: when I replace your df with my csv like df = pd.read_csv('FlightDistanceTest.csv') ... then I get 'Departure_lat' is not defined when it Cleary is in the csv file and it worked fine before?

Comment: Could be spelling, a capital letter, or whitespace (guessing).  Try `print('Departure_lat' in df.columns)`.  Not the same as `print('departure_lat' in df.columns)` (all lowercase) or even `print('departure_lat ' in df.columns)` (space at the end).  List your columns with `print(df.columns)` and carefully check what is in there.

Comment: Actually, if it is a `NameError` and not a `KeyError` it sounds like you have `Departure_lat` in the code somewhere when you probably need `df['Departure_lat']`.  Example: https://ibb.co/RBGkbKF

Comment: If I change the code around so that I perform the equation for the distance first, and then filter out the csv from our airports I get 'Columns must be same length as key'. See https://github.com/AlaiY95/Alai.Github.io/blob/main/Notebooks/test for the code. Also why did you remove duplicated with 'df_airports = df_airports.drop_duplicates(subset ='iata_code', keep='first')' ?

Comment: Comment out the `df = pd.read_csv('FlightDistanceTest.csv')` line and below paste in the mini frame from the answer (the whole `df = pd.DataFrame({'Normalised City Pair': {0: 'Londo...` bit).  Run it.  Should work.  Then comment out the `#Drop duplicates from IATS code column` line and notice the error (something like the indices must be unique and they aren't if there are duplicates in there).  Knowing it works, uncomment the de-dup line, remove the mini frame, uncomment the read_csv and run.  New question for any error and make sure you include the whole file as a download if you can.

Comment: The answer works which is great but the df you have in the answer is only for 5 rows, whereas I want to run the code for the df from csv with 3000 rows (https://github.com/AlaiY95/Alai.Github.io/blob/main/Notebooks/FlightDistanceTest.csv)

Comment: The column `Normalised City Pair` has strings like `2814    Gran Canaria - Canary Isl, Spain - Tenerife - `.  Example: https://ibb.co/c1Lbg51.  So running `.str.split(' - ', expand=True)` creates more than two columns and you're trying to pass the return to only two columns - hence the error. What would you suggest?  Split pattern change, is splitting now required (because you have the airports from the code references?

Comment: If you just commented it out and cleaned up the columns to a new frame you could have: https://ibb.co/yPWjFpz

Comment: ohh ok, every time I was using the split function, I would get 4 new columns (with 2 columns all containing 'none') instead of the 2 I thought I would. The line 2814 makes sense now! Thank you!!!! everything makes sense now